# 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String', how can I solve it?

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

I am learning flutter and I am still trying to understand Null safety...
i am actually having some troubles.

here is my code

```
     static User fromSnap(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
    var snapshot =
        snap.data() != null ? snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic> : {};

    return User(
      username: snapshot["username"],
      uid: snapshot["uid"],
      email: snapshot["email"],
      photoUrl: snapshot["photoUrl"],
      bio: snapshot["bio"],
      followers: snapshot["followers"],
      following: snapshot["following"],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "username": username,
        "uid": uid,
        "email": email,
        "photoUrl": photoUrl,
        "bio": bio,
        "followers": followers,
        "following": following,
      };
  }
```

but the error is coming from here:

```
    username: snapshot["username"],
_TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String')
```

can you please help me understanding this?

Comment: possibly ``snapshot["username"]`` is NULL as it can be because ``snapshot = {}`` if ``snap.data() == null`` !!

Comment: you should return null or something if ``snap.data() == null`` instead of assigning empty map.

Comment: @OMiShah i was getting the error 'type null is not the subtype of type Map<String, dynamic> so i decided to change var snapshot = snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>; into  var snapshot =
        snap.data() != null ? snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic> : {};

Comment: if you have time i can give you more details.

Comment: Checking each map entry before returning User() could help you a little more. Or use something like var u = snapshot["username"] ?? ''; to make sure. But if an entry field is null and it should not be, then there is another issue somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

It's because this part :

```
var snapshot =
        snap.data() != null ? snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic> : {}
```

when the snap.data() is null you return an empty Map so when trying to access snapshot['username'] or any other entry it is going to FAIL because it doesn't exist.

It's better to be handled outside of the model class and throw an exception.

Instead of throwing an exception you can provide a constructor for empty User.